# How to use numba with pandas.Rolling.Apply

Tags: python, pandas, numba, rolling-computation, pandarallel

I want to speed up my following code:

```
values_list = []
indices_list = []

offset_by_w = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset(135)

_ = signal[::-1].rolling(offset_by_w, min_periods=4, closed='both')./
apply(lambda x: [0, indices_list.append((x.index[-1], x.index[0])), values_list.append(x[::-1])][0], raw=True, engine='numba')
```

but I get an error:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'indices_list': Cannot type empty list
```

How can I solve this problem with saving  `values_list` ,  `indices_list` ?

`signal` is `pd.Series` where indexies' type is `Timestamp` and values' type is `float`

I have `pd.Series` like this:

[image: example of input data]

And I want to roll with moving window through the data (by reverse order) to get two lists with `apply` method:

1. [image: values_list]

where the 1st element looks like

[image: 1st element of values_list]

the 2nd element looks like

[image: 2nd element of values_list]

2. [image: indices_list]

where the 1st element looks like

[image: 1st element of indices_list]

the 2nd element looks like

[image: 2nd element of indices_list]

Comment: The `engine='numba'` seems pretty magic here. There is no chance this can work though since Numba does not support Pandas dataframe/series nor Scipy. And even if it would, then typing information are I think missing so Numba can actually JIT the code.  There are some way to make Numba works with Pandas but this is often not trivial and nou need values to have a well-defined type that is typically integer/floats. If you want more help then you need to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with well-defined types.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have the `pandarellel` tag, to use it here you'd change your code to:

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize()

values_list = []
indices_list = []

offset_by_w = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset(135)

_ = signal[::-1].rolling(offset_by_w, min_periods=4, closed='both').\
    parallel_apply(lambda x: [0, indices_list.append((x.index[-1], x.index[0])), values_list.append(x[::-1])][0], raw=True)
```

Comment: I can not use pandaralle, because on ver. 1.6.1 error is 
ValueError: Invalid win_type freq; on ver. 1.4.3 error is
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'prepare_worker.<locals>.closure.<locals>.wrapper'. Python 3.6.8, pandas 1.1.5